# Custom Events with Singleton EventDispatcher, using getDefinition from child

Tags: actionscript-3, events, singleton

EDIT: For whatever reason, it works in the browser but not when compiled/debugged within the IDE.

I can't get my external SWFs to pick up on dispatches from my singleton event manager (EventDispatcher). Here are the particulars:

- I add children from an external SWF using the getDefinition method to my main SWF.
- I'm using a singleton EventDispatcher that is in charge of listeners and dispatching.
- Using a custom event class.

In this code, I am trying to get a mute button to tell the main SWF that the mute icon has been clicked (SoundClipEvent.MUTE_CLICK). After the sound has been muted, it should dispatch the event (SoundClipEvent.STATE) and confirm to the muteIcon the state. Currently, the mute icon successfully dispatches the MUTE_CLICK event and the main SWF document class is able to pick it up. MuteIcon (child SWF MC) hears nothing from the singleton.

Your help in this problem is greatly appreciated!

SoundClipManager.as:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

public dynamic class SoundClipManager extends EventDispatcher {
    private static var isMuted:Boolean;

    public function SoundClipManager(blocker:SingletonBlocker):void {
        super();
        //
        if (blocker == null) {
            throw new Error("Error: Instantiation failed; Use SoundClipManager.getInstance()");
        }
    }

    public static function get muted():Boolean {
        return SoundClipManager.isMuted;
    }

    public static function set muted(value:Boolean) {
        SoundClipManager.isMuted = value;
        //
        SoundClipManager.getInstance().dispatchEvent(new SoundClipEvent(SoundClipEvent.STATE,SoundClipManager.muted));
    }

    public static function getInstance():SoundClipManager {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SoundClipManager(new SingletonBlocker());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public override function dispatchEvent(evt:Event):Boolean {
        return super.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    private static function stateChanged(evt:*) {
        trace('state changed!');
    }        
}

internal class SingletonBlocker {}
```

MuteIcon.as

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
//
public dynamic class IconMute extends MovieClip {
    public function IconMute() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,this.addedToStage);
        //
        SoundClipManager.getInstance().addEventListener(SoundClipEvent.STATE,this.soundClipManagerStateChanged);
    }
    //
    //  Methods, Private
    //

    //
    //  Events
    //
    private function muteClick(evt:MouseEvent) {
        SoundClipManager.getInstance().dispatchEvent(new SoundClipEvent(SoundClipEvent.MUTE_CLICK));
    }
    //
    private function addedToStage(evt:Event) {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,this.muteClick);
    }
    //
    private function soundClipManagerStateChanged(evt:*) {
                    trace("state changed!");
    }
}
```

SoundClipEvent.as

```
package  {
//
import flash.events.Event;
//
public class SoundClipEvent extends Event {

    public static const MUTE_CLICK:String = "muteClick";
    public static const STATE:String = "state";
    //
    public var muted:Boolean;

    public function SoundClipEvent(type:String,muted:Boolean = false) {
        if(muted) this.muted = muted;
        //
        super(type,true,false);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDefinitionByName(className)` method will work only if `className` was mensioned somewhere in your code. You may just import `className` class in a file where you're going to call `getDefinitionByName(className)`. That should help!

Comment: Late comment, but did help! Thanks!